# c macro in macro. how to do it

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I have the following code

```
#define LogError(...) fprintf(stderr, __VA_ARGS__)
```

And I want another macro to print to the error log only in debug mode, so I expect that, with

```
#define DebugLogError(...) \
    #ifndef NDEBUG \
    fprintf(stderr, __VA_ARGS__); \
    #endif
```

code `DebugLogError("hello %s", "world")`
to expand to

```
    #ifndef NDEBUG 
    fprintf(stderr, "hello %s", "world") \
    #endif
```

But the code is not compiling.
How can this be implemented?

Comment: Please don't tag C++ when asking about C.

Comment: It's expanding to `fprintf(stderr, "hello %s", "world")` without `;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C standard does not provide features for using preprocessor directives inside macros. Instead of trying use a `#if` inside a macro, use the `#if` to control how you define the macro:

```
#if defined NDEBUG
    // If NDBUG is defined, define the macro to be replaced by nothing.
    #define DebugLogError(...)
#else
    // Otherwise, define the macro to print a debugging message.
    #define DebugLogError(...) fprintf(stderr, __VA_ARGS__);
#endif
```

However, it is often preferable to modify the macro so it can be used like a function call followed by a `;`, fitting more smoothly into the C grammar:

```
#if defined NDEBUG
    // If NDBUG is defined, define the macro to be replaced by nothing.
    #define DebugLogError(...) \
        do { } while (0)
#else
    // Otherwise, define the macro to print a debugging message.
    #define DebugLogError(...) \
        do fprintf(stderr, __VA_ARGS__); while (0)
#endif
```

Defining them in the latter form will avoid errors where an extra semicolon (in the no-`NDEBUG` case) or missing code (in the `NDEBUG` case) would cause problems, like:

```
if (SomeCondition)
    DebugLogError(stuff);
else
    OtherCode;
```